# How to navigate from Custom UITableViewCell to another view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have three `UIButton` in my custom `UITableViewCell` and i want to navigate to different views on their button actions. When i am implementing navigation it is giving error which is saying like `UITableView` Cell is not having navigation property. Is there any way to make this navigation possible?

Also i am not using storyboard as i am in the middle of the project so i don't want to use storyboard at this point.

Comment: your project is SingleView based application?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Create custom delegate protocol in your custom cell,implement it inside your viewController.

Comment: i found same problem i create protocol still not working any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Notification in the view controller class and call that notification from the method. OR you can use Protocols-delegate approach too.

Comment: is it good practise to use  Notification for this kind of situation??i am facing same problem.but i have doubt while using this notification logic